# How to combine data in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am working on a project that combines data from 4 distributors. These 4 distributors(DCs) deliver to hundreds of different stores. But two different DCs could also deliver to the same store on different days of the week. Or even the same day. I have the data broken down into pivot tables for each DC.

[image: Like this]

I need to combine these 4 pivot tables into one pivot table because these 4 DCs are all combining into one large distribution center. The hard part is two DCs could deliver to the same store. So when I combine the data I need it to combine stores and just add the quantity to the appropriate day for that store. Also, to see high volume days, I take the averages of that stores deliveries on whatever days it gets deliveries, throughout the year. But I need to take the averages off all the DCs and sum them together. I can't just take the overall sum or overall average.

I've tried combining all the data at the start, but again the problem is taking the averages based on the DC and then summing them together. I've tried making 4 different pivot tables in the format that I need, turning the pivot tables back to regular tables and then combining but excel doesn't do it the way I need it to. I've tried everything I could think of.

Comment: This type of problem is called a Transport model, see Practical Management Science by Albright and Winston. There are some examples on here solved using the solver.